# Integrate Facebook with Blackberry application

Tags: blackberry

I am implementing a web application that requires Facebook integration. How do I get my application to open the Facebook login screen when the user clicks a button?

Comment: You're missing a lot of detail from your question. Which Blackberry models are you targeting? What purpose will this integration serve? Are you creating a Java-based application, or a browser-based application?

Comment: i am implementing a java base application for blackberry bold and storm model.. in this application facebook login is compulsory...

Answer (score 0):

There's an open-source BlackBerry Facebook SDK: http://sourceforge.net/projects/facebook-bb-sdk/ which is used by quite a few commercial products.  Good place to start.